# Update .settings file - Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, text-parsing

I have a .Settings file called flexnetls.settings in which is getting deployed in my application. The file is basically key value pairs some of which have values and some of it are empty

PORT=7081

I am writing a script to update the PORT value in the file without affecting the rest of the data. The new value of the port I have successfully queried and set in an variable $availablePort. So far I have researched and used following to get a hashtable for key value pair.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Chitrarth\Desktop\flexnetls.settings" -raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Now if I do $content.PORT I get the desired value in the file, however I am not able to update the same and write it back exactly in the mentioned file. Quick suggestions might help. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What have you tried in your attempt to update? `(Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Chitrarth\Desktop\flexnetls.settings" -raw) -replace "Port=(.*)","New Number" | Set-Content "C:\Users\Chitrarth\Desktop\flexnetls.settings" `

Comment: If this is a file in `INI` format with different section headings, i'd recommend downloading and importing a dedicated ini module like [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.0) and use that instead of a textual replacement.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for a great suggestion. I am exploring the world of Powershell module gallery and I am loving it. Kudos!!